# Why changing a form graphic property will affect the software?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, html-agility-pack

***Description:***

I create a VB.NET Windows Forms application [.net6+] that loads an HTML file using the HtmlAgilityPack library, extracts data from it, and displays it in a list box.

The form contains two combo boxes and a button. The first combo box allows the user to select a type of resource (marble, crystal, sulfur, or wine) and the second combo box allows the user to select a sorting parameter (mine level, carpentry level, or total level). When the user clicks the button, the application extracts data from the HTML document and displays it in the list box based on the user's selections.
The class Island is defined as a container for the extracted data, which includes the island's coordinates, mine level, carpentry level, number of free slots, and total level (the sum of the mine and carpentry levels).

The code loads an HTML file ("pangaia2.html") and sets a label's text to the file name without the extension. It then determines the selected resource type and finds all island tiles in the HTML document that produce that type of resource. For each island tile, it checks if it produces the selected resource type, extracts the mine level and carpentry level, and calculates the number of free slots. If the island meets certain criteria (less than or equal to 7 occupied slots), it creates an Island object and adds it to a list.
The list of Island objects is then sorted based on the selected sorting parameter, and the results are printed to the list box. Each entry in the list box displays the island's coordinates, mine level, carpentry level, and number of free slots.

The ***code*** is full working and fully tested.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports HtmlAgilityPack


Public Class Form1
    Public Class Island
        Public Property Coord As String
        Public Property MineLevel As Integer
        Public Property CarpentryLevel As Integer
        Public Property FreeSlots As Integer
        Public Property TotalLevel As Integer
    End Class

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        Dim filePath As String = "pangaia2.html"
        Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)
        Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
        htmlDoc.Load(filePath)

        ' Set the label text to the file name without the extension
        Label3.Text = fileName
        ' Ottieni il tipo di risorsa selezionato dall'utente
        Dim selectedResourceType As String = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()

        ' Determina la classe CSS corrispondente alla risorsa selezionata
        Dim resourceClass As String = ""
        Select Case selectedResourceType
            Case "Marmo"
                resourceClass = "tradegood2"
            Case "Cristallo"
                resourceClass = "tradegood3"
            Case "Zolfo"
                resourceClass = "tradegood4"
            Case "Vino"
                resourceClass = "tradegood1"
        End Select

        ' Ottieni tutti gli elementi islandTile che hanno il tipo di risorsa selezionato dall'utente
        Dim islands As New List(Of Island)()

        For Each tile As HtmlNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes($"//div[contains(@class, 'islandTile') and not(contains(@class, 'oceanTile')) and starts-with(@id, 'tile_')]")

            ' Check if this island produces the specific resource you're interested in
            Dim tradeGoodType As String = tile.SelectSingleNode($".//div[contains(@class, 'tradegood')]/@class")?.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
            If tradeGoodType <> $"tradegood {resourceClass}" Then
                Continue For
            End If

            ' Get the levels of mine and carpentry
            Dim mineLevel As Integer
            Integer.TryParse(tile.SelectSingleNode($".//div[contains(@class, '{resourceClass}')]/span")?.InnerText, mineLevel)
            Dim carpentryLevel As Integer
            Integer.TryParse(tile.SelectSingleNode($".//div[contains(@class, 'ikaeasy-resource-wood')]/span")?.InnerText, carpentryLevel)

            ' Get the number of occupied slots
            Dim occupiedSlots As Integer
            Integer.TryParse(tile.SelectSingleNode($".//div[contains(@class, 'cities')]/text()")?.InnerText, occupiedSlots)

            Dim totalLevel As Integer = mineLevel + carpentryLevel

            ' Check if the island meets the criteria and add it to the list
            If occupiedSlots <= 7 Then
                Dim island As New Island With {
                    .Coord = tile.GetAttributeValue("title", ""),
                    .MineLevel = mineLevel,
                    .CarpentryLevel = carpentryLevel,
                    .FreeSlots = 16 - occupiedSlots,
                    .TotalLevel = totalLevel
                }
                islands.Add(island)
            End If
        Next

        ' Sort the islands by the selected parameter
        Dim selectedSortParameter As String = ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()
        Select Case selectedSortParameter
            Case "Miniera"
                islands = islands.OrderByDescending(Function(i) i.MineLevel).ToList()
            Case "Carpenteria"
                islands = islands.OrderByDescending(Function(i) i.CarpentryLevel).ToList()
            Case "Totale"
                islands = islands.OrderByDescending(Function(i) i.TotalLevel).ToList()
        End Select

        ' Print the results
        For Each island In islands
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Isola " & island.Coord & " | " & "Miniera: lvl " & island.MineLevel & " | " & " Falegnameria: lvl " & island.CarpentryLevel & " | " & " Posti Liberi: " & island.FreeSlots)
        Next
    End Sub
```

***Issue:***

Whenever Im changing a little thing in the form gui, during debug the software doesn't work anymore. I've been trying to look online, but to be honest, I couldn't find a reason to it.
I registered a gif where I show the correct functioning, then Is enough to change the property FormBorderStyle to make the software to not work anymore.To make it work again, I need to undo the operation. This issue occur also by simply moving a label off some pixels. It shows no warnings/pop up/ messages or stack traces.

[***GIF***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaYUE.jpg)

Does somebody has an idea why is this happening?

***EDIT:***
Apparently, this is a bug from the latest version of Visual Studio as stated [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Event-handlers-disconnect-from-the-objec/10291096) . The Event handlers disconnect from the object code. The bug is on status "Fixed - Pending Release".
To work around the problem, try closing the Form Designer after changes.

To restore the functionality, the lost Handles Button1.Click and Handles MyBase.Load can be retyped manually.
Hopefully this would help somebody and I invite whoever voted to close the question to think twice before to.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what "doesn't work anymore" means. Does it compile? Does it run at all? Can you handle the `Startup` event of the application and hit a breakpoint there? Can you handle the `Load` event of the startup form and hit a breakpoint there? If code is executed, exactly where and how does the code behave different to what you expect? You need to use the debugger that VS provides for the purposes of debugging.

Comment: Not being able to fully explain all that, that's why i registered the gif. But ill give it a try.
Pressing the button simply doesn't reproduce anything anymore. Yes I can handle the startup ( form load ? ) event of the application and hit a breakpoint. The software opens normally, it just doesn't like me changing something in the gui. I've just tried now also adding a new button that print "hello" in the debug tab, same result.

Comment: If you can hit a breakpoint then code is obviously being executed, so you can debug the code to see exactly what it does and exactly how and where that differs from your expectations. If you don't know how to debug properly, stop what you're doing and learn. There's no such thing as software liking or not liking something. The code performs operations. You need to use the tools at your disposal to see exactly what those operations are and exactly what the result of each one is. That's why there's a debugger in VS.

Comment: As far I'm going to agree with you, I would like to invite you to take a look at the gif that I posted. Just give it a try. You can see there is nothing that changes in the code, the only things I'm changing is the position of a label or the form border style property. Really nothing that can influence the code. Might be a bug due to a dev windows version I'm using?

Comment: It doesn;t matter whether anything changes with the code. It matters what the code does with your data. Until you have debugged the ciode then you're just guessing and there's no reason to guess when you have a debugger. If you're not prepared to debug your code then we have nothing further to discuss.

Comment: I am not guessing at all, I said the code fully works and you can clearly see it if only you looked at the gif. I did debug it and used as many breakpoints as i could in both situations, and in both situations I can see that the value are passed through, so the software does what is it built for. 
It just doesn't work as soon as i change something in the gui. That said, do you have any idea on what it could be gone possibly wrong?
I d rather prefer ppl trying to help/give suggestions instead of proposing to close the question.

Comment: *"It just doesn't work as soon as i change something in the gui"*. What does "doesn't work"? That's what I'm talking about. That could mean anything. You need to explain EXACTLY what that means. What EXACTLY are you expecting to see that you don't see or not expecting to see that you do see? Telling us that something "doesn't work" is useless because that's a given if you're posting here at all. You need to explain EXACTLY HOW and WHERE it doesn't work. If you can step through the code line by line and see everything you expect and nothing you don't, how is that "not working"?

Comment: it was a bug in the newest version of VS. It will be solved in the next patch.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Event-handlers-disconnect-from-the-objec/10291096

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is a bug from the latest version of Visual Studio as stated [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Event-handlers-disconnect-from-the-objec/10291096) . The Event handlers disconnect from the object code. The bug is on status "Fixed - Pending Release".
To work around the problem, try closing the Form Designer after changes.

To restore the functionality, the lost Handles Button1.Click and Handles MyBase.Load can be retyped manually.